# Автозаполняемое поле в форме

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-дизайн

Мне нужно сделать поле, которое динамически предлагает возможные варианты при вводе.
Нашел [flexdatalist](http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/), и все бы ничего, только не могу предварительно вставить данные в поле - скрипт все удаляет.
Вот часть документации, где описывается то, что мне нужно. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все делаю так же, как в документации, но выводится просто пустое поле.
Часть кода:

```
<input 
value='{$content[0]['disease_id']}'
type="text" 
class="form-control flexdatalist" 
id="disease_id" 
name="disease_id"
data-url='/json?get=diseases'
data-search-in='name'
data-text-property='name'
data-visible-properties='["name"]'
data-selection-required='true'
data-value-property='id'
data-min-length='0'
required>
```

Кто работал с flexdatalist, подскажите, что же делаю не так, или, что есть из альтернативы этому(обязательно должна быть поддежка выбора нескольких значений)?
Как быть-то?

Comment: Вы проверяли, подтягивается ли json по адресу `/json?get=diseases` и валидный ли он? Добавьте пример данных в вопрос

Comment: Проверял, данные в том же формате,  что и в доках. Когда буду дома добавлю.

Comment: Чем не устраивает это решение? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: В вашем решении есть возможность отправлять id обьекта при выборе его имени из списка? 
То есть, если данные в таком формате: "[{"id":1,"name":"Сергей"},{"id":2,"name":"Влад"}] и выбран обьект с именем Сергей, то на сервер дожна отправиться единица.

Comment: Из коробки такого решения думаю нет, но что вам мешает создать словарь соответствий id -> name и если пользователь выбрал какое-то значение name, то оно однозначно бы отображалось на id привязанный к этому name? И дальше уже на сервер слать этот id?

Comment: Можно пример, пожалуйста, как это сделать на jqueryui?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--
Виджет autocomplete
-------------------
Виджет "autocomplete" позволяет ускорить ввод данных в поле, отображая по мере введения определенные предположения. 
Выбрав одно из предположений пользователь может автоматически завершить ввод.

Предположения выводится в случае, если данные введенные пользователем совпадают со значением одного из элементов из списка данных.

Вы можете подключать к виджету как локальные (т.е. определенные в скрипте на этой же странице) так и удаленные списки 
(т.е. находящиеся на удаленном сервере).

Локальные списки удобны для хранения небольших наборов данных (например список улиц города), а удаленные списки подходят 
для хранения больших наборов данных (например база данных всех городов мира).

Синтаксис:

/* 1. Определяем элемент input, в который будет производиться ввод информации */
<input id='auto' />
/* 2. Превращаем input в виджет autocomplete */
$('#auto').autocomplete({опция1:значение1,опцияN:значениеN})

Подключить к виджету список данных можно с помощью опции source.

С помощью опции minLength Вы можете указать минимальное количество символов, которое должно содержать поле ввода прежде, чем поиск совпадений начнет выполнятся.

-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UI 2-2-1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#auto1").autocomplete({ source: ["Дмитрий", "Мария", "Владимир", "Алексей", "Екатерина", "Олег", "Ольга"] });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Введите имя: <input id="auto1">
</body>
</html>
```